# Examining the impulse response of a given system

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have written a code which takes a vector as input (impulse) and should return another vector (impulse response).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal


y = signal.unit_impulse(8)

def response(y):
      for i in range(8):
      g = np.zeros(len(y))
      g[i] = 3 * y[i] -2 * y[i - 1] + 2 * y[i -2]
return g

print(g)
```

The `signal.unit_impulse(8)` creates a vector with 8 digits, where the first one is 1 and the rest are zero. When I run this, I get `NameError: name 'g' is not defined.` Within the function logic I receive a notification `Local variable 'g' might be referenced before assignment`. I think these two statements are related somehow. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this code by:

- Making sure the indentation is consistent and sensible
- Defining `g` inside the `response` function *before* the `for`-loop (otherwise you will re-initialise `g` during every iteration of the loop)
- After the end of the function definition, define `g` as the output from the `response` function when called with `y` as the input (if `g` is only defined in the scope of your function, then code outside the scope of your function won't have access to it)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal


y = signal.unit_impulse(8)

def response(y):
    g = np.zeros(len(y))
    for i in range(8):
        g[i] = 3 * y[i] -2 * y[i - 1] + 2 * y[i -2]
    return g

g = response(y)
print(g)
```

This code provides the following output:

```
[ 3. -2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to indent your `g`as it is currently not returned by your function.

```py
def response(y):
    g = np.zeros(len(y))
    for i in range(8):
        g[i] = 3 * y[i] -2 * y[i - 1] + 2 * y[i -2]
    return g
```